# How can i make an entire table row clickable so that it checks a checkbox and also changes the color of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a table that, when clicked, checks a checkbox and changes the color of a button from grey to green. However, when the actual checkbox field is checked, the  button does not change from gray to green. I am looking to see how I could make it so that it does.

Here's my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.record_table tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
      $('.submit-btn').toggleClass('green');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="record_table">
  <tr>
    <td id="consent"><input type="checkbox" name="opt_in" id="opt_in" value="true" /> I CONFIRM</td>
    <td id="consentInfo">that all of my information is accurate and consent to be called as provided above</td>
  </tr>
</table>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="form-group" id="space">
          <label for="txt_email" id="formsLabel"></label>
        <input name="btn" type="submit" class="form-control submit submit-btn" id="btnSubmit" value="SUBMIT" title="submit" placeholder="SUBMIT" />
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where is `submit-btn` and where is the `green` class ?!! and how you plan to click on `tr` when its not visible behind td's?!

Answer (score 0):

If the only error is:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

That means jQuery is being imported after your script, or not imported at all.

You need import jQuery library properly.

Comment: This is just the snippet bug not the OP question (fixed)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that when you trigger a click in the checkbox you also trigger a click in the tr element (because the checkbox in inside the tr element).

I make an implementation that is working here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwrNqN

```
$('.record_table tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $('#opt_in').trigger('click');
    } else {
        $('.submit-btn').toggleClass('green');
    }
});
```

Is not the best approach, because you are triggering twice, but for sure you can work with. :)

You can also do something like this to avoid triggering the click in the tr element twice:

```
$('.record_table tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      if($('#opt_in').is(':checked'))
        $('#opt_in').prop('checked',false);
      else
        $('#opt_in').prop('checked',true);
    }
    $('.submit-btn').toggleClass('green');
});
```